# How to represent this type of "matrix multiplication"?

Tags: matrices

Let's say I have 2 matrices that I want to multiply:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix}·\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}5 & 3 & 4 \\ 11 & 9 & 10 \\ 17 & 15 & 16\end{bmatrix}$

However, if I want to multiply each term of the matrix with the one in the same position from the other matrix, as below, what symbol should I use for the operation? I'm guessing both '·' and 'x' are incorrect, because it is not a matrix multiplication.

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{bmatrix}·\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 0 \\ 7 & 0 & 9\end{bmatrix}$

Thanks

Comment: Also, can anyone please tell me how to add math in the questions?

Comment: Hi, this is the pointwise product of matrices, sometimes called the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). Wikipedia uses the notation $A \circ B$.

Comment: See [mathjax quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I kept on searching 'matrix multiplication with numbers in the same index'  but I couldn't find anything

Comment: You're welcome, cheers and welcome to math.se.

Comment: For a matrix, just write: `$A=\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2 \\ 4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$`